# How to get PK id of a table in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

Consider the following snippet
Here my table name is **g_user**

```
Yii::app()->user->id  returns as "admin"

    $criteria1=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria1->select='g_user_id, name,email,e_role_id';
    $criteria1->condition='name ='."'".Yii::app()->user->id."'";
    $usr = User::model()->find($criteria1);
    echo "USER ID: ".$usr['g_user_id'];
    echo "NAME: ".$usr['name'];
    echo "EMAIL: ".$usr['email'];
```

The outcomes will be 
USER ID:
NAME: admin
EMAIL: test@gmail.com

What im trying to ask means "Why $usr['g_user_id'] returns empty value"? But it has value in database as 19. I dont know why. Please help to solve this issue

Comment: What do you have if you do `$usr->getAttributes();` at the end?

Comment: you need to write $usr->g_user_id instead of $usr['g_user_id'] because find always return a single record so its not an array, its a single record.

Comment: if i use $usr->g_user_id it gives value of username as admin

Comment: $usr->getAttributes() returns Array ( [email] => admin@gmail.com [e_role_id] => 3 [g_user_id] => [lastname] => [password] => [name] => admin [phone] => [job] => [is_active] => [created] => [updated] => [createdby] => [updatedby] => [mobile] => [crm_campaign_id] => [crm_customer_id] => [is_operator] => [username] => )

Comment: Here there is no value for g_user_id, but this has value in database

Comment: see what comes in `print_r($usr)`.

Comment: User Object ( [name] => admin [password] => [rememberMe] => [_identity:User:private] => [g_user_id:User:private] => [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [email] => admin@gmail.com [e_role_id] => 3 ) [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t [_errors:CModel:private] => Array ( ) [_validators:CModel:private] => [_scenario:CModel:private] => update [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => )

Comment: can you post exact names of attributes of your table in database?

Comment: and also post upper portion of your model in which names of attributes are given

Comment: Just comment out the '$criteria1->select=' line so that it selects * and do a var_dump or something again, see if that contains your id. Either your table is wrong or you have a typo in the field name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are more than one record with name = admin. Findbyattributes Return the first.
Attention: Your code is not safe against sql injection